# android problems sending app to emulator from using terminal

Tags: android, terminal, adb

I have launched an emulator with a:

```
android avd
```

(although the android developers site said do it from platform-tools, i did it from tools because the android command was there ,and not in  platform-tools).  Anyway the AVD manager appeared and I started one, and it launched just fine.

Then I tried to send my app to the emulator so (following the android developers instructions) I do a:

```
   adb install /newApp.apk
```

the command prompt jumps to the next line and just blinks.....when i check the emulator nothing has changed...where am i going wrong???

Comment: are you sure your apk is located in your root folder? That's usually pretty uncommon in most Unix environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have started the emulator try

```
adb devices
```

to check if you can see it

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
```

then you can proceed with the install

```
adb install <path-to>/newApp.apk
```

Comment: i tried this, but i ran into a problem...once i launch the avd, i can't do a "adb devices"..the prompt just blinks

Comment: i opened another terminal and i navigated to the platform tools folder and i ran "adb devices" and i got the message.......List of devices attached 
emulator-5554 offline......but then i noticed that the emulator screen was locked when i unlocked it i got ......List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device..... then i ran the ........adb install <path-to>/newApp.apk......(also from the second terminal) and it succeeded...Thank You dtmilano...

Answer (score 0):

Something looks strange about that path.  If the apk is in the same directory you are launching the command from then you don't need that '/'.    If this is a linux machine it would be './' for the same directory unless your apk is all the way up on root but that would be bad :)